# Permanently use certificate for site on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate

I have installed a certificate in chrome for a website I am running. Whenever I go to the site, chrome prompts me for which certificate I want to use. I only have one certificate for the site. Is there a way to auto-accept that certificate so I am not prompted each time I visit the site.

I am running Chrome on Ubuntu.